# Chaining useEffects with early return

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, early-return

**Example to make the context clear:**

I am trying to render a component with two sets of data coming from API calls. I am also returning early if the first API call fails. The second API call depends on the data of the first API result. I don't want to combine both effects because that would mean the whole of component does not render till I get bot API results.

**This is the psuedo code**

```
const DataList = () => {
  const [dataFromEffect1, setDataFromEffect1] = useState([]);
  const [dataFromEffect2, setDataFromEffect2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi1 = async () => setDataFromEffect1(await (await fetch('/api1')).json());
    callApi1();
  }, []);

  // early return so that all the complex logic below is not called on ever render
  if (!dataFromEffect1) return <div>No Data1</div>;

  const data1 = complexMassagingOver(dataFromEffect1); // data1 to be used in second effect

  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi2 = async () => setDataFromEffect2(await (await fetch('/api2', { headers: data1 })).json());
    callApi2();
  }, [data1]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* no need to null check here, because of the early return on top */}
      {dataFromEffect1}
      {/* null check required here, so that it doesnt render this child component to not render till we get the data for it */}
      {dataFromEffect2 ? (
        <div>
          {dataFromEffect2}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Problem**

The above code does not work because you cannot add a useEffect conditionally (the early return messes it up)
Trying to find the best workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just creat a component for `dataFromEffect2`:

```
const DataList = () => {
  const [dataFromEffect1, setDataFromEffect1] = useState([]);
  const [dataFromEffect2, setDataFromEffect2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi1 = async () =>
      setDataFromEffect1(await (await fetch("/api1")).json());
    callApi1();
  }, []);
  
  if (!dataFromEffect1) return <div>No Data1</div>;

  const data1 = complexMassagingOver(dataFromEffect1); // data1 to be used in second effect

  return (
    <div>
      {dataFromEffect1}
      <Component data1={data1} dataFromEffect2={dataFromEffect2} setDataFromEffect2={setDataFromEffect2} />
    </div>
  );
};

const Component = ({ data1, dataFromEffect2, setDataFromEffect2 }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi2 = async () =>
      setDataFromEffect2(
        await (await fetch("/api2", { headers: data1 })).json()
      );
    callApi2();
  }, [data1]);

  return <div>{dataFromEffect2}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. It will kill both useEffects, but it will not run the second one unless it retrieved data from the first. Also, I did not fix this in your code but you should not use `async` code within `useEffect`. This can lead to memory leaks and unnexpected bugs. You are also not cleaning up the fetch from within the `useEffect`. Academind has a nice blog explaining how to fix this and what will happen if you keep the code like this https://academind.com/tutorials/useeffect-abort-http-requests/

```
const DataList = () => {
  const [dataFromEffect1, setDataFromEffect1] = useState([]);
  const [dataFromEffect2, setDataFromEffect2] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const callApi1 = async () => setDataFromEffect1(await (await fetch('/api1')).json());
    callApi1();
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    if(!dataFromEffect1.length) return;
    const data1 = complexMassagingOver(dataFromEffect1); // data1 to be used in second effect
    const callApi2 = async () => setDataFromEffect2(await (await fetch('/api2', { headers: data1 })).json());
    callApi2();
  }, [dataFromEffect1]);

  // early return so that all the complex logic below is not called on ever render
  if (!dataFromEffect1) return <div>No Data1</div>;


  return (
    <div>
      {/* no need to null check here, because of the early return on top */}
      {dataFromEffect1}
      {/* null check required here, so that it doesnt render this child component to not render till we get the data for it */}
      {dataFromEffect2 ? (
        <div>
          {dataFromEffect2}
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Two options ( I went with the second one for now):

1. create a separate component for abstracting the second useEffect as suggested by @viet in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68947916/5367829).
2. move the useEffect above the early return, but I will have to duplicate the if conditions inside the effect. As described by in the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68947920/5367829).